# I created an app gateway and linked web app but getting 502 Bad Gateway, even that probe is healthy

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I've set up an application gateway and connected the web app to it. I've also configured a DNS zone to direct to the app gateway. I've followed the app gateway setup as outlined in the documentation. The probe indicates it's in good health, and when conducting diagnostic insights, it also reports no detected issues.

I run diagnostic insights and probe health check. they showed no issue. but I am still unable to access the web site I am getting error: 502 Bad Gateway
Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've identified the problem. Initially, I had configured everything in the app gateway on port 80. The issue was that the backend (web app) was actually on port 443. After adjusting the backend settings to HTTPS, everything started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I created Azure app service and Application Gateway and added backend setting like below:

[image]

When I check probe health it is in healthy state:

[image]

Now when I try to access the web site, I got the same error `502 Bad Gateway Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2`

[image]

**To resolve this issue**, make sure to add service endpoint in your virtual network.

*In your virtual network -> service endpoint add  `Microsoft.web`* with subnet like below

[image]

This will route the traffic from virtual network to Azure back bone network.

In Azure app service -> networking -> access restriction try to allow access from virtual network to access the network like below:

[image]

When I tried access the web site I got result successfully like below:

[image]

If still the issue persists, check the below references:

[Bad Gateway errors - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502)

[Azure Application Gateway - 502 Bad Gateway error - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1166561/azure-application-gateway-502-bad-gateway-error) by GitaraniSharma